# How to build this sql query by queryBuilder in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

How can I get following query in Yii2 framework using queryBuilder? I want to use a operator format, but I can't understand what can I do with the OR condition...

```
SELECT "user_data".* FROM "user_data" LEFT JOIN "user" ON "user_data"."user_id" = "user"."id" WHERE (create_date <=  NOW() - INTERVAL '1 WEEK') AND ((("user_id"='1') and ("last_visit" IS NULL))  OR ("email_status"=0));
```

For now my code looks like this:

```
UserDataModel::find()
            ->joinWith('user')
            ->where("create_date <=  NOW() - INTERVAL '1 WEEK'")
            ->andWhere(
                [
                    'and',
                    ['is', 'last_visit', null],
                    ['in', 'user_id', $array],
                    ['or', ['email_status' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE]],
                ]
            )
            ->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

And this code generates this query:

```
SELECT "user_data".* FROM "user_data" LEFT JOIN "user" ON "user_data"."user_id" = "user"."id" WHERE (create_date <=  NOW() - INTERVAL '1 WEEK') AND (("last_visit" IS NULL) AND ("user_id"='1') AND ("email_status"=0))
```

How to fix it?

Comment: see docs: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#orWhere-detail

Comment: @Luuk This question is about Yii 2, you have linked documentation for Yii 1.1.

Comment: OK, so i should have linked to https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail  , But what did the question asker from not looking at the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest conditions in this way:

```
UserDataModel::find()
    ->joinWith('user')
    ->where("create_date <=  NOW() - INTERVAL '1 WEEK'")
    ->andWhere([
        'or'
        [
            'and',
            ['is', 'last_visit', null],
            ['in', 'user_id', $array],
        ],
        ['email_status' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE],
    ])
    ->createCommand()
    ->getRawSql();
```